# TwitteR API in r-statistics , user_timeline request

Tags: r, twitter

I just tried to use the TwitteR package in R, and wanted to create a script that gets all the last tweets of all members of a twitter-list.
So what I did is this:

```
library(twitteR)
library(rjson)
library(httr)

consumer_key <- xxx
consumer_secret <- xxx
access_token <- xxx
access_secret <- xxx
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)


TwGetListUser <- function(twlist, twowner) {
  api.url <- paste0("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members.json?slug=",
         twlist, "&owner_screen_name=", twowner, "&count=5000")
  response <- POST(api.url, config(token=twitteR:::get_oauth_sig()))
  response.list <- fromJSON(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))

  users.names <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$name)
  users.screennames <- sapply(response.list$users, function(i) i$screen_name)
  users <- list(users.names, users.screennames)
  return(users)
}

users <- TwGetListUser("bundestagsabgeordnete", "TwitterDE")

for(i in 1:length(users[[1]])) {
  tl <- userTimeline(screenname, n=100)
  Sys.sleep(25)
  if(length(tl) > 0) {
    df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tl, function(x) x$toDataFrame()))
    tmp <- data.frame(df$text, df$created, screenname)
  } else {
    tmp <- data.frame("NA", "NA", screenname)
  }
  if(i > 1) {
    tweets <- merge(tweets, tmp, all=TRUE)
  } else {
    tweets <- tmp
  }
}
```

and I get always the same error:

```
Fehler in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'
```

And this everytime after 150 requests, even if I put Sys.sleep(25) after every request, so there are less the 150 requests in 1 hour. (And I thought the limit ist 180 in 15 min in API 1.1??)

Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: Where do you get that: What does `traceback()` tell you after the error occurs?

Comment: `> traceback()
    3: stop("OAuth authentication error:\nThis most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'")
    2: check_twitter_oauth()
    1: setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, 
       access_secret) at #4`